# How to write a binary search with two comparisons which can return 0 when the target is not found?

Tags: c, binary-search

Here is my pseudo-code,

```
int BinarySearch(int arr[],len, target)
{
   if len<=0 {
      returns 0
   }

   mid = len/2

   if target == arr[mid] {
      return 1
   }

   if target<arr[mid] {
      return BinarySearch(int arr[],mid, target)
   }
   else {
      return BinarySearch(int arr[]+mid+1,len-mid-1, target)
   }
}
```

If I do it in 2 comparisons, it will no longer return 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  I've changed 'code' to 'pseudo-code' because what you've shown is emphatically not C — you're missing parentheses and semicolons, and your recursive 'calls' are completely mixed up in the syntax used.  Your pseudo-code is pretty erratic too. You compare `target` to `mid` and to `arr[mid]`, for example.

Comment: Side-note: In many CPUs/compilers, sequential comparisons like target == arr[mid] else if target < arr[mid], assuming primitive types, actually only performs one comparison (it executes a single comparison instruction, then a pair of conditional jumps that check the different flag registers set by the single comparison). Probably not what you're looking for, but it's worth noting.

Comment: Your pseudo code looks good to me.